# Tracking any change in an table on SQL Server With Python

Tags: python, sql-server, change-tracking

How are you today?

I'm a newbie in Python. I'm working with SQL server 2014 and Python 3.7. So, my issue is: When any change occurs in a table on DB, I want to receive a message (or event, or something like that) on my server (Web API - if you like this name). 
I don't know how to do that with Python. 
I have an practice (an exp. maybe). I worked with C# and SQL Server, and in this case, I used "SQL Dependency" method in C# to solve that. It's really good!
Have something like that in Python? Many thank for any idea, please!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Now I got the same issue, did you find anything? I'll research and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know many things about SQL. But I guess there are tools for SQL to detect those changes. And then you could create an everlasting loop thread using multithreading package to capture that change. (Remember to use time.sleep() to block your thread so that It wouldn't occupy the CPU for too long.) Once you capture the change, you could call the function that you want to use. (Actually, you could design a simple event engine to do that). I am a newbie in Computer Science and I hope my answer is correct and helpful. :)

Comment: :) Thank you for your help. I love your idea about "thread". Of course SQL  have a tool to do that, I mean it's "Trigger". But as I know, trigger is used to detect change in database and do something "In Database" too. But, I want to receive notification from my server automatically. SQL Dependency in C# is a thread too, I think so. But in Python, I don't have any idea about that. I'm missing something?